# Is it possible to include individual bar labels inline with the bars on a vertical google chat line graph?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create a simple google line graph to get an overview of time worked. [This (modified) example](https://jsfiddle.net/1xbztg0w/1/) from the Google Chart API documentation is almost perfect but requires you to mouse over each bar to see that bars name.

Data Example:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day', 'Jane', 'John', 'Joe'],
      ['13th', 3, 7, 3],
      ['14th', 1, 3, 4],
      ['15th', 5, 8, 2],
      ['16th', 4, 8, 4]
    ]);
```

There may be dozens of bars per group so relying on the legend may not be easy. Is there a way to include group labels and bar labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `annotations` to place text on the bars

`annotations` are added as separate columns,
the annotation will display on the series column it follows

however, `annotations` are not supported by *Material* charts

instead, recommend using a *Core* chart, with the following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet, a `DataView` is used to add the `annotations`...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart', 'bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Jane', 'John', 'Joe'],
    ['13th', 3, 7, 3],
    ['14th', 1, 3, 4],
    ['15th', 5, 8, 2],
    ['16th', 4, 8, 4]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(1)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    2,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(2)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    3,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(3)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    }
  ]);


  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 8
      }
    },
    hAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3'],
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

following is an example of moving the bar labels to the left / start of bar

problem is the chart will move the label back on any interactivity, such as hover

thus, need to use a `MutationObserver` to know when interactivity has occurred

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  setBarLabels();
  var observer = new MutationObserver(setBarLabels);
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });
});
```

then need to know which `text` elements are bar labels,
we can test against the column labels

also need to know what the new x-location should be,
use `chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation(0)` to get the x-location of the value 0
then adjust for the length of the label...

```
function setBarLabels() {
  var xLoc = chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation(0) + 4;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(barLabel) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (data.getColumnLabel(i) === barLabel.innerHTML) {
        barLabel.setAttribute('x', xLoc + (barLabel.innerHTML.length * 4));
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Jane', 'John', 'Joe'],
    ['13th', 3, 7, 3],
    ['14th', 1, 3, 4],
    ['15th', 5, 8, 2],
    ['16th', 4, 8, 4]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(1)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    2,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(2)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    },
    3,
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getColumnLabel(3)
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'annotation'
    }
  ]);


  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 8
      }
    },
    hAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3'],
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setBarLabels();
    var observer = new MutationObserver(setBarLabels);
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function setBarLabels() {
    var xLoc = chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getXLocation(0) + 4;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(barLabel) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        if (data.getColumnLabel(i) === barLabel.innerHTML) {
          barLabel.setAttribute('x', xLoc + (barLabel.innerHTML.length * 4));
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to align the annotations left, if need be?

Comment: not via standard options, but you can change the x attribute of the label when the chart is finished drawing -- i have an example i can share tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you for giving me a couple options!